# How to make size of generic type explicit in Ada?

Tags: size, ada, gnat

I am trying to compile this code: https://github.com/RanaExMachina/ada-fuse

Unfortunately when building I get this error:

```
fuse-system.ads:147:04: size clause not allowed for variable length type
```

This seems to be a problem because in the code it tries to set the size of a record which has a generic type as an entry. This seems to be a new error as the developer didn't had that problem back when he wrote that 2.5 years ago. Unfortunately he isn't able to help me on short notice but I have to get that library going. I am a bit helpless in fixing this issue however.

Basically it seems to me that I have to somehow tell gnat how big that type is going to be, which - contrary to gnat's believe - is a priori knowable: it is an access type. Either in the `record` or the generic type definition.

The relevant parts are:

```
fuse-main.ads:
  package Fuse.Main is
    package IO is
      new Ada.Direct_IO (Element_Type);
    type File_Access is access IO.File_Type;

fuse-system.ads:
  generic
    type File_Access is private;
  package Fuse.System is
  ...
    type File_Info_Type is record
      Flags       : Flags_Type;
      Fh_Old      : Interfaces.C.unsigned_long;
      Writepage   : Interfaces.C.int;
      Direct_IO   : Boolean := True;
      Keep_Cache  : Boolean := True;
      Flush       : Boolean := True;
      Nonseekable : Boolean := True;
      Fh          : File_Access;
      Lock_Owner  : Interfaces.Unsigned_64;
    end record;
  type File_Info_Access is access File_Info_Type;
  pragma Convention (C, File_Info_Type);
  for File_Info_Type'Size use 32*8;
```

My gnat version is: 4.9.2-1 (debian jessie)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*You* know that `File_Access` is an access type, but within `Fuse.System` the compiler doesn’t; all it knows is that it’s definite and supports assignment and equality. The actual could be hundreds of bytes.

To tell the compiler that it *is* an access type, try something like this (I compressed it into one package for my convenience, on Mac OS X, hence the 64-bit pointer size; it compiles OK):

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
package Fuse_Tests is

   generic
      type File_Type is limited private;
      type File_Access is access File_Type;
   package Fuse_System is
      type File_Info_Type is record
         Fh : File_Access;
      end record;
      for File_Info_Type'Size use 64;
   end Fuse_System;

   type File_Access is access Ada.Text_IO.File_Type;

   package My_Fuse_System is new Fuse_System
     (File_Type   => Ada.Text_IO.File_Type,
      File_Access => File_Access);

end Fuse_Tests;
```

Or, an alternative suggested in the comments:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
package Fuse_Tests is

   generic
      type File_Type;
   package Fuse_System is
      type File_Access is access File_Type;
      type File_Info_Type is record
         Fh : File_Access;
      end record;
      for File_Info_Type'Size use 64;
   end Fuse_System;

   package My_Fuse_System is new Fuse_System
     (File_Type => Ada.Text_IO.File_Type);

   --  if needed ...
   subtype File_Access is My_Fuse_System.File_Access;

end Fuse_Tests;
```

Comment: I wonder whether it would make sense (or be helpful at all) to make File an incomplete type here. I think I would try that, and define the access type in the generic itself, so that the generic can be instantiated in the same public part where the actual File is declared.